# Calling function of instances in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying create a hashmap in View function having instances of subviews , which I do in init method of View. But it is giving an error that init() of view doesnt exist. Am I doing anything wrong here? Thanks in advance.

http://jsfiddle.net/3fR4R/1/

```
view = function() {
    var subview;
    init = function() {
        subview['search'] = new searchSubView();
    }
}

check = function() {
    console.log("clicked");
    var view1= new view();
    view1.init();
}

searchSubView = function() {    
}
```

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/BLa8U/1/

Comment: What happened with the missing `var` declarations?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/BLa8U/2/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've created a function and assigned it to an implicit global, which has nothing to do with the `view` function or instances created by it.

You can assign the function either by assigning to `this.init` within the constructor, or by putting it on `view.prototype`.

So either:

```
view = function() {
    var subview;

    // Note: You need code here to initialize `subview`

    this.init = function() {
        subview['search'] = new searchSubView();
    };
};
```

or (note that I've made `subview` a property):

```
view = function() {
    this.subview = /* ...initialize subview... */;
};
view.prototype.init = function() {
    this.subview['search'] = new searchSubView();
};
```

---

Side notes:

1. You're falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) a lot in that code. You need to declare variables.
2. The overwhelming convention in JavaScript code is to use initial capitals for constructor functions, e.g., `View` rather than `view`.
3. You're also relying on [automatic semicolon insertion](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.9), which I wouldn't recommend. Learn the rules and apply them, not least so you can minify/compress/compact your code safely.

Comment: `subview` is not initialized, will be undefined.. in the second version `subview` will not be available in the prototyped scope

Comment: @TJ, will `subview` be accessible in the prototype method?

Comment: @ArunPJohny & maček: Thanks, I was looking at the forest, hadn't gone back and looked at the trees.

Comment: Thanks...  worked after initializing subview and using this with init.